# How to switch the poles of the SPDT switch in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am drawing a circuit with **circuitikz** that have lots of SPDT switches.
I want to show the circuit at two different moments: once, when all the SPDT switches connected to out1 and the second with all of them to out2.
Is there any simple way to do this?

Here is a working example of what I am trying to code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{circuitikz}
    % Switches
    \draw (0,2) node[spdt,xscale=1,anchor=in] (Swp) {};
    \draw (0,0) node[spdt,xscale=-1,anchor=in] (Swc) {};
    \draw (0,-2) node[spdt,xscale=1,anchor=in] (Swn) {};

    % Capacitors
    \draw (Swp.in) to[C,l_=$(C_s + \Delta C)$] (Swc.in);
    \draw (Swn.in) to[C,l^=$(C_s - \Delta C)$] (Swc.in);

    % Voltages
    \draw (Swp.out 1) node[anchor=west] {$V_{in}^+$};
    \draw (Swn.out 1) node[anchor=west] {$V_{in}^-$};
    \draw (Swp.out 2) node[anchor=west] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swn.out 2) node[anchor=west] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swc.out 1) node[anchor=east] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swc.out 2) node[anchor=east] {$V_{ref}$};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn the appropriate values into a parameter-dependant values and use a conditional test:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\def\mycircuit{%
    % Switches
    \draw (0,2) node[spdt,xscale=1,yscale=\value,anchor=in] (Swp) {};
    \draw (0,0) node[spdt,xscale=-1,yscale=\value,anchor=in] (Swc) {};
    \draw (0,-2) node[spdt,xscale=1,yscale=\value,anchor=in] (Swn) {};

    % Capacitors
    \draw (Swp.in) to[C,l_=$(C_s + \Delta C)$] (Swc.in);
    \draw (Swn.in) to[C,l^=$(C_s - \Delta C)$] (Swc.in);

    % Voltages
    \draw (Swp.out \myone) node[anchor=west] {$V_{in}^+$};
    \draw (Swn.out \myone) node[anchor=west] {$V_{in}^-$};
    \draw (Swp.out \mytwo) node[anchor=west] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swn.out \mytwo) node[anchor=west] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swc.out \myone) node[anchor=east] {$V_{cm}$};
    \draw (Swc.out \mytwo) node[anchor=east] {$V_{ref}$};
}

\newcommand\swapot[1]{%
\ifnum#1=1\relax
  \def\value{1}
  \def\myone{2}\def\mytwo{1}
\else
\ifnum#1=-1\relax
  \def\value{-1}
  \def\myone{1}\def\mytwo{2}
\fi\fi%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
\swapot{1}
\mycircuit
\begin{scope}[xshift=5cm]
\swapot{-1}
\mycircuit
\end{scope}
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. I'd rather use 1 for identity and -1 for a change; but \relax, not a space, is a variant I should choose from time to time.